# AngularJS remove href

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I want to remove href attribute from 'a' tag (work like a plain text) and I use this code in my directive file:

```
.directive('rhHasLinkFor', function () {
    return{
        priority: 10000,
        restrict: 'A',
        compile: function (el, attr) {
                el.href.remove();

        }

    }
});
```

but it doesnt work,what's the problem?

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
.directive('rhHasLinkFor', function () {
    return{
        priority: 10000,
        restrict: 'A',
        compile: function (el, attr) {
                el.removeAttr('href');
        }

    }
});
```

Comment: Can you provide a fiddle illustrating your problem? [Here is](http://jsfiddle.net/joshdmiller/HB7LU/) an empty angular fiddle.

Comment: That one totally doesn't work. It's impossible to identify the problem on broken sample.